# How to invoke repository's Jenkinsfile stages from a custom Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to create a custom Jenkins pipeline which will bind together artifacts generated by multiple Jenkins jobs. Each of these jobs operates on different repositories (basing on their own Jenkinsfiles). These Jenkinsfiles' stages do such things like creating archives, compiling some code, etc.

One may say that I could use artifacts from single jobs and then bind them together, but the problem is that this high-level pipeline would checkout these repositories on a specific `git tag`, generate some files signatures, compile release application version, etc.

To give you a brief idea, this is a part of one of my Jenkinsfiles, let's say from a `componentA` repository:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Cleanup library') {
      steps {
        sh 'rm -rf .git .gitignore .gitmodules Jenkinsfile .some_useless_files'
      }
    }
    stage('Pack library') {
      steps {
        sh 'tar -czf my_arch.tar.gz ./*'
      }
    }
    stage('Save artifacts') {
      steps {
        archiveArtifacts 'my_arch.tar.gz'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the main pipeline:

```
node {
    dir('compA') {
        git url: 'git@some.path.com:my_lib/componentA.git'
        sh('git checkout $compA_rv')
        load 'Jenkinsfile'
    }
    // some other stuff
    //...
}
```

Output:

```
+ git checkout compA_rv
Note: checking out 'compA_rv'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD is now at 5a840d0... Some commit
[Pipeline] load
[Pipeline] { (Jenkinsfile)
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/apk-release@2
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Cleanup library)
[Pipeline] sh
+ rm -rf .git .gitignore .gitmodules Jenkinsfile .some_useless_files
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Pack library)
[Pipeline] sh
+ tar -czf my_arch.tar.gz ./my_arch.tar.gz
tar: ./my_arch.tar.gz: File shrank by 448 bytes; padding with zeros
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Save artifacts)
Stage "Save artifacts" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // load
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // dir
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

It seems that this pipeline loads the Jenkinsfile and executes it in another directory `Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/apk-release@2`, thus it cannot create archive out of nothing.

As I am new to Jenkins pipelines, do you have any suggestions how to solve that issue?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I think you could just switch to pipeline entirely and use a custom workspace

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    node {
      label 'my-defined-label'
      customWorkspace '/some/other/path'
    }
  }
  stages {
    stage('Example Build') {
      steps {
        sh 'mvn -B clean verify'
      }
    }
  }
}
```